# Why the distribution function in Kolmogorov theorem must be continuous?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

The Kolmogorom theorem states that if the distribution function is continuous, the following statement is true:

${\displaystyle {\sqrt {n}}\sup \limits _{x\in \mathbb {R} }\left|{\hat {F}}(x)-F(x)\right|\to K}$

I am interested in why the distribution function should be continuous. Is there a counterexample for the theorem for the case of discontinued function?

Comment: I have the gut feeling that this is neither about the Hahn-Kolmogorov theorem, nor the Kolmogorov extension theorem, nor the Kolmogorov continuity theorem, nor Kolmogorov's three-series theorem, nor Kolmogorov's zero-one law, nor the Chapman-Kolmogorov equations, nor Kolmogorov's inequality, nor the Landau-Kolmogorov inequality, nor the Fréchet-Kolmogorov theorem, but possibly somehow about the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest counterexample is to get samples from Bernoulli distribution $B(1/2)$ and find the limit in distribution straitforward.

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n\sim B(1/2)$ are independent r.v.'s.  Then 
$$\hat F(x)=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf 1_{\{x_i\leq x\}}=\begin{cases}0, &  x<0\cr 1-\bar x, & 0\leq x < 1\cr 1, & x\geq 1\end{cases}$$
and 
$$F(x)=\begin{cases}0, &  x<0\cr 1/2, & 0\leq x < 1\cr 1, & x\geq 1\end{cases}$$
Then 
$$
{\sqrt {n}}\sup \limits _{x\in \mathbb {R} }\left|{\hat {F}}(x)-F(x)\right|=\sqrt{n}\left|\,\bar x - \frac12\,\right| \xrightarrow{d} |Z|,
$$
where $Z$ has normal distribution $\mathcal N(0, 1/4)$ and $\xrightarrow{d}$ is convergence in distribution. You can compare some table values to see that this is not the Kolmogorov distribution.

More simple is to get sample from degenerate distribution.